# How can find specefic user data from get api by express js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-hooks

backend:

```
app.get('/booking', async (req, res) => {
  const customer = req.query.customer;
  const query = { customer };
  const result = await bookingCollection.find(query);
  res.send(result);
});
```

frontend:

```
const [booking, setBooking] = useState([]);
const [user] = useAuthState(auth);

useEffect(() => {
  const url = `http://localhost:5000/booking?result=${user.email}`;
  console.log(url);
  fetch(url)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => setBooking(data));
}, [user]);
```

Answer (score 1):

At first ,to find specific user from database you should have some key like( userId , contact) based on this key you can find the data of particular user in express.
for exapmle in my case "contact" is the key i am using to filter particular person data.

i have appointments table and he has option of seeing his appointments.

```
  app.get("/myorders", (req, res) => {
//taking user  contact number from query parameter
    db.query(`SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE Contact=${req.query.contact} `, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.send({ result, message: "you're booked appointments", success: true });
        }
    });
});
```

FrontEnd:
using axios to call api from react

```
 const [mySlots, setMySlots] = useState([]);
const number = localStorage.getItem("phonenumber");
await axios
    .get(`http://localhost:3001/myorders`, {
        params: {
            contact: number
        }
    })
    .then((res) => setMySlots(res.data.result));
```